# Failed to execute command on return code 1

Tags: windows, chef-infra, bootstrapping

I've been trying to bootstrap a windows node using WinRm, but I keep getting the following error.

```
root@ubuntu01:~/chef-repo/roles# knife bootstrap windows winrm 10.44.120.19 --winrm-user administrator --winrm-password 'Redhat#10' --node-name Win_Node
Creating new client for Win_Node
Creating new node for Win_Node

Waiting for remote response before bootstrap.10.44.120.19 . 
10.44.120.19 Response received.
Remote node responded after 0.0 minutes.
10.44.120.19 AMD64
Bootstrapping Chef on 10.44.120.19
10.44.120.19 Rendering "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-24877-1471330698.bat" chunk 1 
...
10.44.120.19 Checking for existing directory "C:\chef"...
10.44.120.19 Existing directory not found, creating.
...
10.44.120.19  echo.-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
10.44.120.19 ) 1>C:\chef/trusted_certs/wildcard_opscode_com.crt 
10.44.120.19 'chef-client' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
10.44.120.19 operable program or batch file.
10.44.120.19 ...
10.44.120.19 C:\Users\Administrator>SET "PATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Azure Site Recovery\home\svsystems\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\thirdparty\rrdtool-1.2.15-win32-perl58\rrdtool\Release;C:\thirdparty\rrdtool-1.2.15-win32-perl58\rrdtool\bindings\perl-shared;C:\thirdparty\php5nts;C:\thirdparty\php5nts\ext;C:\windows;C:\strawberry\perl\bin;C:\strawberry\c\bin;C:\thirdparty\Cygwin\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\Redist\;C:\opscode\chef\bin\;C:\ruby\bin;C:\opscode\chef\bin;C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin" 
10.44.120.19 
10.44.120.19 C:\Users\Administrator>chef-client -c c:/chef/client.rb -j c:/chef/first-boot.json 
ERROR: Failed to execute command on 10.44.120.19 return code 1
```

Can somebody help me with this??

Comment: Can you please try to run with debug "-VV" for more logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error too. However, I have got rid of this chef-client error.

Error : 'Chef-client' is not recognised an external or internal command

Resolution :
Log onto your node, under programs, select Chef-client and click on repair, then reboot your system and then re-run the bootstrap command .

However, the later part of the error ' Failed to execute command.. ' still will be present.

See my below output for reference
[my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11UyF.jpg)